Can I Use a Buck Converter to Step Down USB Power to 3.3V and Increase Current?
I'm a newbie in electronics and working on a project where I want to power a custom FPGA board via USB-C 2.0. The USB source provides 500mA.
I’m planning to use a buck converter to step down the 5V to 3.3V, and I need around 1 or 1.5A at 3.3V for my board. My question is:
Is it possible to increase the current at the lower voltage using a buck converter?
Are there any specific requirements for choosing the right buck converter for this application?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Hi,
Since your source, USB can only deliver 5V and 500mA which is 2.5W, then it is not possible to supply 3.3V with 1A, 3.3W.

You are only allowed to draw 500mA if your device declares this in a configuration descriptor, and this configuration is activated by the host. Before that, the limit is 100mA, which is the safe limit for a device connected to a bus powered four port hub. There are also negotiation protocols for higher power demands, such as resistor based detection of power bricks (up to 2A) and USB-PD.

is there a way to use a USB-C 3.x host port? Because then we are talking about 0.9/1.5/3 A from 4.45–5.25 V. While power negotiation is required by the standard, many hosts tolerate >0.1 A currents even without proper enumeration. P.S. are we talking about 1.5A peak or avg?

@ChristianB. better speaking i can say it's 800mA peak current consumption

Your USB output provides 0.5A at 5W, or 2.5W.
An ideal buck converter will lower the voltage without losses, so you would still have 2.5W available at 3.3V.
But 2.5W at 3.3V is 0.757A.
So no, while it is more than 500mA, you cannot draw 1A or 1.5A at 3.3V. No buck converter, even an ideal one, can provide it with 5V 500mA input.
And indeed, your board must negotiate first if 500mA is available, before it is allowed to consume 500mA.

could you advise me what i can do in this case? the board has some RGBs , 4-digits display alongside an accelerometer and i need at least 1A. I saw some videos they were using even an LDO with an 1A output current. And i saw in some datasheets that the load current can be in the amount of some mAs.

@Alaa Well if you can't use USB you need to use an external power supply.
